# How FIlter Order Items Collection?

Tags: magento2, collection

How Filter(make custom array) Order Items Collection when view order from front end admin page sales order grid.

Comment: `front end admin page sales order grid.` means admin orde view page?

Comment: Yes exactly. when i click on **view** then order detail page open. In this page a section named  "Item Ordered" where all products of order listed. i want to just display those order items that has relate to current admin id store. I am developing multi vendor site. i already save "current_admin_id" with product and order placeing .
Just Guid me where "Item Order" section comes from i want to just override and mcustom.
Thanks in advance